# When did photographic film stop being used in satellites?

Tags: artificial-satellite, history, earth-observation

Some early observation satellites took pictures on photographic film and the film was dropped towards Earth and picked up by airplanes (e.g. [Corona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_%28satellite%29)). What was the last satellite to use photographic film? When was the last roll of photographic film dropped from a satellite down to Earth?

Comment: Would an astronaut with a film-based camera count?

Comment: @gerrit If the astronaut is in orbit around the Earth, I guess he counts as one of Earth's satellites

Comment: You might want to specify "by which countries," as I rather doubt you'll find any public info on Soviet / Russian or  early  China  spy satellites.

Comment: For US, https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjxq6r_4KnqAhUDpp4KHTS-BloQFjAFegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cia.gov%2Flibrary%2Fcenter-for-the-study-of-intelligence%2Fcsi-publications%2Fcsi-studies%2Fstudies%2Fvol-58-no-2%2Fpdfs%2FWaltrop-Catching%2520the%2520End%2520of%2520an%2520Era-June2014.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2E7EihOWvFcuuN8zZ-JzWA indicates 11 October 1984.

Comment: @gerrit - not too many astronauts (or their film) have been dropped and picked up by an airplane!

Comment: @JonCuster No?  I picture returning astronauts in capsules descending (=dropping) to the Earth with a parachute somewhere remote, and I doubt they make it back to Houston without boarding an airplane...

Comment: @gerrit - fair enough, but that seems to go against the spirit of the question....

Comment: Wouldn't film be susceptible to increased radiation when not protected by the atmosphere?  I'm assuming there was some sort of shielding involved in space cameras for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 15):

Zenit flights continued until 1994
http://www.zarya.info/Diaries/Zenit/Zenitindex.php

Comment: Were they the last flights to use photographic film?

Comment: http://www.satmilmagazine.com/story.php?number=30747315 indicates that some later Yantar satellites also used film drops.

Comment: Hmmmm... and "The Yenisey series, also known as Orlets-2, was based on the Don series but carried up to 22 film return capsules. It is also likely that the satellites’ optics systems allowed them to take images at a higher resolution than that achieved by satellites of previous generations. The first of the series was launched on 26 August 1994 with a second launched on 25 September 2000." from previous link